# How to set equal height for columns under different parent div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I have three columns under two different parent divs. I need to set equal height for these three columns.

The issues in my case are:

1. 3 columns are under different parent divs, cannot use **display: table** and **table-cell** method
2. Got a tab-list in col-2, which will alter the block height when you click on different tabs
3. I tried JS to set the equal height, but failed:

   a) JS got the wrong height for col-2, cause it calculates the total height for all sections but not the one that is active.

   b) JS sets a fixed height value. When I shrink the window size or click on different tabs in col-2, the column height won't adjust accordingly. The content inside col may overflow.

**HTML code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="left-wraper">
    <header>Head1</header>
    <div class="col-1">
      <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <section id="menu1" role="tabpanel">
        <p>
          This is menu1<br> This is menu1<br> This is menu1<br> 
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-wraper">
    <span>Head2</span>
    <div class="col-3">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <p>
        sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.left-wraper {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #b3ffcb;
}

.right-wraper {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  background-color: #ffccef;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e6ccfe;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffeecd;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #b3d9ef;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56chL/101)

Need a way to dynamically set equal height for block purple, yellow and blue in the above demo. Not just on load, but also when click on different tabs or resize the screen.

Comment: This wiki page is a bit old but has a lot of useful options for this: http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Columns_in_CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `display:flex`:

```css
.left-wraper {
  display: flex;
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  padding: 27px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #b3ffcb;
}

.right-wraper {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  background-color: #ffccef;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e6ccfe;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffeecd;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #b3d9ef;
}
.outer_div {
  display: flex;
  }
.left-wraper > header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer_div">
  <div class="left-wraper">
    <header>Head1</header>
    <div class="col-1">
      <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#munu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <section id="menu1" role="tabpanel">
        <p>
          This is menu1<br> This is menu1<br> This is menu1<br> 
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-wraper">
    <span>Head2</span>
    <div class="col-3">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <p>
        sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text<br> sample text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is close, but somehow Head1 falls into the same level with col-1 and 2. Does flex has anything to do with this? Need head1 to be above on col-1 and 2

Comment: Is there a way to keep Head1 above inside flex wrapper? I tried witdth 100% and position: absolute, did not work.

Comment: I think this is what you wanted originally? where you want to keep head1?

Comment: This is what I need

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a utility class to seperate things you do in css and js.
I've updated your fiddle with that in mind. The code below will work for you on load and click. I'd need to see it in more context for resize as it maintains the height in the fiddle or resize.

```
var $body = $('body');
findHeight('.findHeight');

function findHeight(el){
    var heightArr = [];
    $(el).each(function(){
        heightArr.push($(this).outerHeight());
    });
    var tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heightArr);
    $(el).css('height', tallest);
    heightArr = [];
}

$body.on('click', 'div[class^="col-"]', function(){
    findHeight('.findHeight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d16b7932/

You'll notice I've added the class of findHeight to the elements in question. You can change that to whatever you'd like. Just make sure to do it in the js as well.

Comment: I tried your code, when I shrink the window, "sample text" will overflow col-2. As I said, using JS to set height has this issue.

Comment: ok your usage case is a little unclear. are you looking to set the height on load, on click or both? the heights currently remain consistent on resize.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear part. Yes, need it to work on load, tab click and window resize.

Comment: I guess I'm unsure what you mean by text overflow, can you explain a little further?

Comment: When you shrink the window size, "sample text" will flow out of col-2 box cause JS set a fixed height value. Other contents may also overflow for the same reason.

Comment: to handle that you should use a media query in your css. you can override the height set with js by using !important

Answer (score 0):

¿Are you looking for something like this?

CSS
`.col-height {
  height: 100vh;
}`

HTML
`...
<div class="col-1 col-height">
...
<div class="col-2 col-height">
...
<div class="col-3 col-height">`

Comment: That is way too big. Just need the max height among them to set the equal height.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use flexbox, a handy module that helps with layouts. Here's a link to a guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You essentially want to add flexbox css to your left and right wrappers' parent div and make some additions to the css as seen here:

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="left-wraper">
    <header class="header">Head1</header>
    <div class='col-wrapper'>
    <div class="col-1">
      <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#munu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <section id="menu1" role="tabpanel">
        <p>
          This is menu1
          <br> This is menu1
          <br> This is menu1
          <br>
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-wraper">
    <span>Head2</span>
    <div class="col-3">
      <header>Topic 2</header>
      <p>
        sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
        <br> sample text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.col-wrapper {
  flex: 5;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.left-wraper {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #b3ffcb;
  flex-grow: 2;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.right-wraper {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  background-color: #ffccef;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e6ccfe;
  order: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffeecd;
  flex: 3 0px;
  order: 2;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #b3d9ef;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ydoxj8m/

Good Luck!

Comment: Is there a way to keep Head1 block above col-1, 2 inside left flex wrapper? I tried witdth: 100% and position: absolute, did not work.

Comment: With the configuration above, the head1 block does stay above the col1 and col2 divs ( see http://jsfiddle.net/8ydoxj8m/ ).

Comment: With the configuration, wrapper left and right have the same height, but col-1, 2 do not have the same height as col-3. If I add display: flex to wrapper-left. col-1, 2, 3 have the same height, but head1 does not stay above.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, you can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ydoxj8m/